# How to delimitate the given string to get output in an array in java?

Tags: java, delimiter

How to delimit the given string to get output of the given string in an array in Java ?

```
 Str= "[[["eee","wwww","fff","0","1","3"]]]"
```

Output:

```
 array[0]=eee 
 array[1]=wwww 
 array[2]=fff 
 array[3]=0 
 array[4]=1 
 array[5]=3
```

I am getting the above input after JSON parsing in android studio. The values like "eee","wwww" are stored in mysql database and I want to retrieve the values only replacing all other.

Comment: if that really is what you want to parse and that is **not a valid string literal in Java anyway** so some real code you have tried.

Comment: needs to get closed as **Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
    String[] arr =Str.split("\\b(.*?)\\b");
    for (int i = 1; i<arr.length-1;i++) {
        if(arr[i].endsWith(","))
           System.out.print(arr[i].subSequence(0, arr[i].length()-1)+ " ");
        else
            System.out.print(arr[i]+ " ");

     }
```

Output:

```
  eee  wwww  fff  0  1  3
```